# Read file from HDFS using Hadoopy

Tags: python, hadoop, hdfs, hadoopy

I am using Python to read file from HDFS. The library used is **Hadoopy**.
Earlier, I was able to write the corresponding file to HDFS using Hadoopy.
But it does not read from HDFS and store into the local file system.

The code is pasted below:

```
import hadoopy
hdfs_path = 'hdfs://localhost:54310/user/hduser/sample1'
def main():
    hadoopy.readtb("abc4.txt",hdfs_path)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**How to read the file using Hadoopy ?**

Comment: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/bwhite/3186206/raw/e96c72d514df8f33ee789dfc889697a7bf404ab0/dataout_readtb.py

Comment: ok, solved it now.